# How to go to previous activity optimized?

Tags: java, android, events, sdk, android-activity

Hello here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, loginPage.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

}

I would like to know how to go back to this MainActivity when my loginPage has been pressed by the back event.

Here is the loginPage :

```
public class loginPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connexion);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    finish();
}
```

}

I don't know what to put in onBackPressed..

Comment: What do you mean by nicely? Put an animation, like a slide effect?

Comment: Sorry my english is bad, by nicely i mean "optimized"

Comment: Maybe by not overriding *onBackPressed*. When you press hardware button, the OS will automatically finish your activity (if you have not declared finish in the previous activity). If you don't need to do something else, this overrided method in your code seems useless. Trust the OS.

Comment: The thing is when I press the back event with or without the function nothing happen... :/ It doesn't go back to the MainActivity

Comment: do you have a webview in login activity?

Comment: i think you always have start a new intent, like you did in the onClick-function in your MainActivity class

Comment: Even if you remove all the method (the *onBackPressed* method itself)?

Comment: Jeffrey -Hum no I don't but it may be possible that it's because of the AVD? Toxz - What do you mean ? Fllo - Yes

Comment: Certainly not @Toxz! If you do that, all the stuff that you loaded, changed, uploaded in the previous activity will be reupload like the first time you called this activity.

Comment: Try to change the *loginPage* extension with `ActionBarActivity` and then remove the *onBackPressed* method (all of it) and re-try to press the hardware back button. Also, make sure that you enabled the *Hardware keyboard present* and the *Skin* (and not *No Skin*) by editing the AVD.

Comment: It came from the AVD...thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Android OS call `onBaskPressed()` when the back button is pressed and call `finish()` for the current activity.
Then, the system automatically redirects you to the previous Activity (only if you **didn't call** `finish()` in the previous one). So, you don't need to override this method because the OS does it for you.

If press the hardware back button on your emulator doesn't do anything, edit the emulator and make sure that you enable the **Hardware keyboard present** by checking it. Also, don't use **No skin**.

[image: AVD edition]